# dependency web application inside another web application

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a Spring MVC based rest api API_1. I want to create another api API_2 which will use all the same system vars of API_1. Basically I want to create a separate Spring boot rest service and add it as a dependency to API_1.

Is i possible to do this? I don't want to change packaging type from war to ear. 
Only thing is I want this api separate project is because I think this feature can be used by other api's accross the project.

I was thinking if I can somehow load API_2 in API_1 after adding the dependency and some configs in web.xml or pom xml (adding some plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a jar out of war, you can consider [maven overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)

> An overlay of a WAR file, is simply a Maven project that uses another
>   project's WAR output as a dependency, rather than a project's JAR.
>   When the overlay project is built, the underlying project's WAR file
>   is exploded and files in the overlay project added to it. If an
>   overlay project has a file with the same path and name as a file in
>   the underlying WAR it will replace it.

Comment: This will require more configurations than my expectations.. Even not sure if it will handle spring Mac vs spring boot